# Auto scroll a horizontal div

Tags: javascript

I thought this would be fairly easy but I'm stuck.

My code is executing and ignoring the setTimeout.

I am getting the scroll width of my element, then saying while `i` is less than the width (`flavoursScrollWidth`), move the horizontal scroll 1px along every second.

That isn't what is happening though, it just executes each pixel movement almost instantly.

I also tried taking the code out of the load event and taking the setTimeout out of the while loop. Then creating a function containing the while loop, and calling the function in a setInterval. Didn't help.

```js
const flavoursContainer = document.getElementById("flavoursContainer")
const flavoursScrollWidth = flavoursContainer.scrollWidth

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  let i = 0
  while (i < flavoursScrollWidth) {
    setTimeout(flavoursContainer.scrollTo(i, 0), 1000)
    console.log(i)
    i++;
  }
})
```

```css
.container {
  width:300px;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="flavoursContainer">
    This is a really long sentence to demo my code, it's just going on and on. Still going. I should have used some default placeholder text but I've started now so I'll keep going.
</div>
```

Comment: It seems like you're wanting `setInterval` if you intend to do this every second. What you have here is just scheduling 49 timeouts to execute after 1000ms, which is the same second. You could also try to do something like `setInterval(..., 1000*i)` so that each timeout is 1 second after the last.

Comment: Additionally, you need to put a callback function in `setTimeout`, not straight JavaScript. If there is no callback function the contents will be executed immediately. Try changing `setTimeout(flavoursContainer.scrollTo(i, 0), 1000)` to `setTimeout(function(){flavoursContainer.scrollTo(i, 0)}, 1000*i)`.

Comment: Try if this works for you: `setTimeout(function(){ flavoursContainer.scrollTo(i, 0)}, 1000)`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would suggest using `setInterval` rather than `setTimeout` and checking if the container is scrolled to the end. I also found that if you scroll at a faster interval (every 15ms, for instance) you get a smoother user experience.

```js
const flavoursContainer = document.getElementById('flavoursContainer');
const flavoursScrollWidth = flavoursContainer.scrollWidth;

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  self.setInterval(() => {
    if (flavoursContainer.scrollLeft !== flavoursScrollWidth) {
      flavoursContainer.scrollTo(flavoursContainer.scrollLeft + 1, 0);
    }
  }, 15);
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="flavoursContainer">
  This is a really long sentence to demo my code, it's just going on and on. Still going. I should have used some default placeholder text but I've started now so I'll keep going.
</div>
```